# Como Calcular valores lidos num Array e armazenar o cálculo numa única variável em PHP

Tags: php, array

O array possui a seguinte estrutura abaixo:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [value] => 0
            [total] => 100
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [value] => 1
            [total] => 50
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [value] => 0
            [total] => 300
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [value] => 1
            [total] => 150
        )
)
```

O array que tiver o índice value 0 sempre vai ser o total maior do que o array que tiver o índice value 1, então preciso varrer e diminuir o valor do índice total do array que tiver o índice value 0 com o total do array que tiver o índice value 1, ficando assim:

No primeiro loop fazer o cálculo:
$total = 100 - 50;
$total = 50;

No segundo loop fazer o cálculo:
$total = 300 - 150;
$total = 150;

E ao final de todos os loops ter todos os valores que foram subtraidos somados e totalizados, no exemplo acima ficaria em 200 (50, do primeiro loop + 150, do segundo loop).

Alguém sabe como implementar essa lógica no PHP para me ajudar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sugiro mudar a lógica pra simplificar e realizar o cálculo em apenas um loop.

Para realizar loops no PHP pode-se utilizar `while`, `foreach`, `for`...

Por exemplo com um foreach.

```
$total = 0;
foreach ($array as $element) { 
   if ($element['value'] == 0) {
      $total += $element['total'];
   }else{
      $total -= $element['total'];
   }
}
```

Sugestões de referencias:
https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.control-structures.php

Answer (score 0):

Minha sugestão é andar pelo "for" de 2 em 2 pegando os array de value = 0 e pegar a posição seguinte para realizar a somatória e guarda-las em um novo array para depois fazer a nova somatório.

Segue o exemplo abaixo:

```
$arrInicial = [0 => ['value' => 0, 'total' => 100], 1 => ['value' => 1, 'total' => 50],
               2 => ['value' => 0, 'total' => 300], 3 => ['value' => 1, 'total' => 150]];
$n = count($arrInicial)/2;

$arrSoma = [];
$total = 0;
for ($i = 0; $i <= $n; $i = $i+2) {
  $arrSoma[]['total'] = $arrInicial[$i]['total'] - $arrInicial[$i+1]['total'];
  $total = $total + ($arrInicial[$i]['total'] - $arrInicial[$i+1]['total']);
}

echo $total;
```